# Is this a subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> For a fixed element $a$ of a group $G$, prove or disprove: The set $H = \{xa\mid x \in G\} $is a subgroup of $G$.

Clearly it is nonempty since if $e$ is the identity of $G$, then $ea = a$.

Now suppose $m,n \in H$. Then we know that there exits $g_1, g_2 \in G$  such that $m=g_1 a$ and $n = g_2 a$. Thus $mn = g_1ag_2a$ and hence $mn = (g_1ag_2)a$. Since $(g_1ag_2)\in G$, $mn \in G$.

How can I prove that if $g \in H$, then $g^{-1} \in H$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Define the map $\phi: G \rightarrow H$ given by $\phi(g) = ga$. See if you can show that this is a bijection.

Edit: To more directly answer your question (establishing the existence of inverses), let $g' \in H$, i.e. $g' = ga$ for some $g \in G$. Then note that $a^{-1}g^{-1} \in H$, since $a^{-1}g^{-1}a^{-1} \in G$. Then $g'(a^{-1}g^{-1}) = ga(a^{-1}g^{-1}) = e$.

Comment: well if i said that $mn = g_1ag_2a$ then $mn = (g_1ag_2)a$ and so $mn \in H$

Comment: Ok, though that doesn't really pertain to this suggestion. $\phi$ defines a map from $G$ to $G$, since multiplication by a fixed element of $G$ lands you back in $G$. Further, suppose $\phi(g_{1})=\phi(g_{2})$. Then $g_{1}a=g_{2}a$, which shows $g_{1}=g_{2}$ via right multiplication by $a^{-1}$. This establishes injectivity. Can you show surjectivity similarly to show that $H = G$?

Comment: well for any $g \in G$ we can choose x to be $ga^{-1}$ and so $xa = ga^{-1}a = ge = g$

Comment: Indeed. Perfect! :) (Hopefully my edit has answered your question about inverses. If not, feel free to comment asking for clarification!)

Comment: thank you very much , but i still wonder can i prove that for any $g \in H$ then $g^{-1} \in H$ ?? i also want to prove it the direct way

Comment: No problem. Did you see the edit? This establishes the existence of inverses, as requested.

Comment: I can't thank you enough :) u are awesome !